# How to search in Cloudant by using Search Index

Tags: node.js, cloudant

Sorry for novice question.
I'm trying to query Cloudant db with sample code (taken from official gitHub cloudant repository):

```
To query using the index, use the `.find()` method.

~~~ js
db.find({selector:{name:'Alice'}}, function(er, result) {
  if (er) {
    throw er;
  }

  console.log('Found %d documents with name Alice', result.docs.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < result.docs.length; i++) {
    console.log('  Doc id: %s', result.docs[i]._id);
  }
});
~~~
```

I need to search through all document in the db and to improve this query performance I created Search Index (especially for field "name"). But how do I define in the code that I want to use the index and which one if there are some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_find` API endpoint, which backs the `.find()` method will use the index automatically, *if it can*. Sometimes, it can't -- typically because the actual query doesn't actually match the index. It's worth reviewing the documentation for [Cloudant Query](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#finding-documents-by-using-an-index) for better understanding of this mechanism.

It is possible to specify the actual index for the query to use via the parameter `use_index` -- but I haven't checked if this is implemented in the node.js client, but in most cases it shouldn't be necessary.

There is another useful API endpoint called [_explain](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#explain-plans) that will show you the indexes found, or if the query falls back on a full db scan (which you want to avoid!).

Note that when you're using `_find` (`.find()`), you are actually using something called Cloudant Query, as opposed to Cloudant Search. The distinction is important, as Cloudant Search is a different query mechanism that is on offer.